# Why is my <table> behaving this way?

Tags: html, html-table

I'm having a problem where the content of two td's are not in line with each other.  I cannot reproduce this in a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5cyrtv2d/.  Weird.

Here's my code:

```
<tr>
      <td>
            <img src="images/Affiliations/aaa.logo_.color_.jpg" />
      </td>
      <td>
            <div class="contactContent">
                 AAA is a federation of 51 independently operated motor clubs throughout North America. AAA is a not-for-profit member service organization with more than 51 million members. They provide services to its members such as travel, automotive, insurance, financial, and discounts. AAA Approved Auto Repair facilities have been thoroughly inspected and are tested annually to ensure they meet – and often surpass – the stringent, demanding quality service criteria established by AAA.
            </div>
      </td>
</tr>
```

Here's the rendered output:
[image]

The class of "contactContent" has no bearing on what's going on - I removed the class and it still rendered like above.  However when I replace the image with text, everything is in line like I would expect.

Comment: Could you please reproduce the issue in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @Lal actually I cannot reproduce this in a fiddle, see: https://jsfiddle.net/5cyrtv2d/

Comment: What was this rendered using?

Comment: Oh it seems to be correct in your fiddle..so i think the problem is with some other css..are you specifying any other css in in your page?

Comment: @ShaunLoftin I am using Chrome.

Comment: I believe it's one of my CSS files - I remove the CSS's I'm using and the problem goes away...

Comment: Ah the problem is my reset.css.. not sure what is in it that is causing the problem though.

Comment: oh great..if you could add the reset css in your fiddle, we can debug it for you..

Comment: It was the vertical-align:baseline; CSS that was causing the issue

Comment: @Lal He is required to post a complete but minimal example of his markup here, **not a jsfiddle** which will get this question closed. [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my reset.css.  I had the vertical-align:baseline; set applied to my table/cells/rows, which caused the issue.  Removed that, and everything works as expected now.